# How Can I make modal to become full-screen in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Here is my modal code:

```
    let modal = Modal.create(DailyReportPage);
    this.nav.present(modal);
```

It works fine on Phone, however on the tablet it looks like this:
[image]
What I want is to make it look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I apply this style:

```
ion-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: but it'll make all the modal in app to fulscreen, can we make some specific modals full screen and leave rest of the modals as it is.

Comment: I find that by adding this css, the modal overlaps the status bar. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: @Omar You can use the `cssClass` option when presenting the modal, then use the class in the css, like: `ion-modal.fullscreen { ... }`

Comment: This works on iphone, but on ipad it overlaps the statusbar

Comment: Above CSS should be kept in app.scss or the particular modal page ?

Comment: in ionic 5 I had to add this to global.scss and with width/height "!important" added

Answer (score 9):

You can override the related Ionic Sass variables in file `variables.css`:

```
$modal-inset-width: 100%;
$modal-inset-height-large: 100%;
```

Documentation (current version is 3.9, but I use this with 3.7): 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: This one is the right approach. I'm not sure it is the best but we should look inside css because on small screens Modal is fullscreen. So easy tweaks inside css variables must work. I've added this for iOS too: `$modal-ios-border-radius: 0;`

Comment: I find that this overlaps the status bar.  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: This seems to work on iphone, but on ipad it overlaps the statusbar

Answer (score 2):

You should follow [Modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

A Modal is a content pane that goes over the user's current page. Usually it is used for making a choice or editing an item.

So If you want to show full screeen. I think you create new page and push to it

```
this.nav.push(SamplePage, {item: item});
```

Comment: `nav.push` behaves very similar to expected for fullscreen Modal. Great suggestion. +1

Answer (score 1):

Apply this style inside your scss file

```
ion-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    } }
```

It should be out side of your **selector**.

ex: -

```
page-mymodal {
    //page CSS Codes
}
ion-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Will that make it global? How can you make it only for that page. Why doesn't that work inside the "page-mymodal"

Comment: If you need to do global changes , you can do that in app/app.scss file. ion-modal is a component of ionic 2. It won't override inside the page-mymodal. So we should keep it outside and it affects only in this page.